# What does "static type of expression" in the return type description of the getClass() method mean?

Tags: java, generics

The [getClass()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) method of the `Object` class returns a *`Class <? extends |T|>` where `|T|` is the erasure of the static type of the expression on which the `getClass()` method is called*.

I don't understand the meaning of 'static type of expression'. Does this mean static context? Maybe I need some examples to understand better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
String str = "a string";
Class<? extends String> c = str.getClass();
```

The expression on which the `getClass()` method is called is `str`. The static type of `str` is `String`. So in this case, that method returns a `Class<? extends String>`, where `String` is the erasure of the static type of `str`. In this case, the erasure part is not important because `String` is not a generic class.

Here's another example:

```
ArrayList<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
Class<? extends ArrayList> c2 = strList.getClass();
```

In this case, the expression is `strList`. The static type of `strList` is `ArrayList<String>`, and the *erasure* of that type is `ArrayList`. This is where the *erasure* part is important because it's telling you any type parameters of the static type will not be available at runtime. This is due to [type erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Because of type erasure, the following is invalid:

```
ArrayList<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
Class<? extends ArrayList<String>> c2 = strList.getClass(); //error: incompatible types
```

Answer (score 2):

The static type of an expression is the declared type of the variable; it's what the compiler sees.  The actual runtime (dynamic) value of the expression may end up being a subtype of the  static type.  So for example:

```
Object o = functionReturningString();
Class<?> cls = o.getClass();
```

is valid, but

```
Object o = functionReturningString();
Class<? extends String> cls = o.getClass();
```

is not.  Although:

```
Class<? extends String> cls = functionReturningString().getClass();
```

would be ok

Comment: Actually I think the only way to return `Class<String>` without the wildcard is to use `String.class` - `getClass()` still plays it safe even with that last example.

Comment: Cool, +1 for covering the `? extends` aspect.